# WF4.5 Hosted: How to add activites to the toolbox?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How do we add activities to the toolbox in a hosted workflow?

Can we add items from another class?  Can the toolbox be added dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/08/14/how-to-create-a-custom-activity-designer-with-windows-workflow-foundation-wf4.aspx